Write one test class to cover service and controller classes or a test class for each one?
I would like to get your opinion on the best approach to write test classes for this scenario.
Suppose I have a service class with some functions, and two LWC controllers call these functions. These LWC controllers don't have any other logic.
The options I am considering are:

Create a test class with proper unit testing for each class, even though I would have very similar code in each test class.

Create a test class for each class, but only write proper unit testing in ServiceClassTest. In Controller1Test and Controller2Test, I would only write a line to call each method of the controller, like this: testmethod(){ Controller1.method1(); }

Create one test class that covers all three classes.


ServiceClass
___Method1
___Method2
Controller1
___Method1 => ServiceClass.Method1()
___Method2 => ServiceClass.Method2()
Controller2
___Method1 => ServiceClass.Method1()
Thanks in advance

Be careful about the usage of "opinion." We do not generally permit opinion-based or open-ended questions. That said, I think this question is sufficiently scoped to allow only a handful of answers to exist, and may prove useful to others if answered objectively.

The second option provides the best long-term strategy for unit testing. Each test class should cover the logic for one class. This makes it easy to identify which class is being tested, and insulates the tests from changes that may happen in different locations.
For example, the unit test for a controller class should verify that the controller methods aren't throwing exceptions at the wrong time, etc, but should not be concerned about the service class that the controller might be using. From the test's perspective, the service class should be a "black box."
Similarly, the test class for the service class should not be concerned about any control that might call the service class, but instead verify that the output for each method is correct. Each test should verify only as much as it needs to, and not any more than that.
Two factors that will greatly aid future development is to have a trigger framework that can be turned off via static methods/variables, and a common test utility class that provides factory methods for the various types of data you might want to set up for each test.
However, there is merit in having one or more additional test classes that handle end-to-end testing. If there are scenarios where multiple classes may run at the same time, a comprehensive test that calls of those methods can help catch governor limit problems early. Not every class or method may need this, but should be considered a tool that you can use to help monitor resource usage.

The approach I take is to use Apex tests to confirm business logic and not to confirm the behaviour a single Apex class. (This is not an absolute rule, but a starting point.) You can Google to see the debate about what a "unit" is; I'm arguing that this:

A unit is the smallest testable part of an application.

is not the best guide to choosing what a unit is.
The idea is that implementation detail does not matter and changes over time. Having Apex tests that imply that the implementation detail matters can be a block to such changes and also results in low value test code bloat. So focus on tests of the controller classes and other API endpoint classes rather than feeling obliged to write a test for every class. Code coverage is not achieved on a 1:1 basis of class and test class, but rather across the full set of test classes.
For sure governor limits can make this hard to do; one of the big frustrations of Apex.
For your case of:

These LWC controllers don't have any other logic.

where the logic has been factored out into a service class the "unit" is the service class and its methods so I'd likely write a ServiceClassTest class. And not write any tests for the controller classes if they are trivial. Aiming for 100% code coverage is usually counter-productive.
